# PHP Text Extract from Scanned PDF

Tags: php, pdf, text

I need help in Text Extract from Scanned PDF

Is it possible to extract or read the text from a scanned image or an pdf using PHP. If so how it can be done... I am able to read the text from a normal pdf but when it comes to scanned pdf,code is not working.

Comment: Because that is an image and it's not text. You should look for an OCR solution.

Comment: Thanks Mihai,is there any web services provided for this?

Comment: There are a lot of them, mostly with subscription. Try Google.